# How to authenticate paho mqtt subscriber client in C language with cloudamqp?

Tags: c, mqtt, paho, ansi-c

I want to connect mqtt subscriber c client to cloudamqp but don't know how to authenticate with C program? Are there any other C language clients with working example. I am using linux.

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "MQTTClient.h"

#define ADDRESS     "tcp://buck.rmq.cloudamqp.com:1883"
#define CLIENTID    "ExampleClientSub"
#define PAYLOAD     "Hello World!"
#define QOS         1
#define TIMEOUT     10000L
#define USERNAME    "sakhdjs"
#define PASSWORD    "B7JnaMNF2evJmWpT_WZn"

char TOPIC[12];



volatile MQTTClient_deliveryToken deliveredtoken;

void delivered(void *context, MQTTClient_deliveryToken dt)
{
    printf("Message with token value %d delivery confirmed\n", dt);
    deliveredtoken = dt;
}

int msgarrvd(void *context, char *topicName, int topicLen, MQTTClient_message *message)
{
    int i;
    char* payloadptr;

    printf("Message arrived\n");
    printf("     topic: %s\n", topicName);
    printf("   message: ");

    payloadptr = message->payload;
    for(i=0; i<message->payloadlen; i++)
    {
        putchar(*payloadptr++);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    MQTTClient_freeMessage(&message);
    MQTTClient_free(topicName);
    return 1;
}

void connlost(void *context, char *cause)
{
    printf("\nConnection lost\n");
    printf("     cause: %s\n", cause);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MQTTClient client;
    MQTTClient_connectOptions conn_opts = MQTTClient_connectOptions_initializer;
    int rc;
    int ch;
    printf("Enter toic name to subscribe ");
    scanf("%s", TOPIC);
    //printf("Enter host adderss with format like tcp://localhost:1883 ");
   // scanf("%s", ADDRESS);
   
    MQTTClient_create(&client, ADDRESS, CLIENTID,
        MQTTCLIENT_PERSISTENCE_NONE,NULL);
    conn_opts.keepAliveInterval = 20;
    conn_opts.cleansession = 1;

    MQTTClient_setCallbacks(client, NULL, connlost, msgarrvd, delivered);

    if ((rc = MQTTClient_connect(client, &conn_opts ,USERNAME,PASSWORD)) != MQTTCLIENT_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Subscribing to topic %s\nfor client %s using QoS%d\n\n"
           "Press Q<Enter> to quit\n\n", TOPIC, CLIENTID, QOS);
    MQTTClient_subscribe(client, TOPIC, QOS);

    do 
    {
        ch = getchar();
    } while(ch!='Q' && ch != 'q');

    MQTTClient_unsubscribe(client, TOPIC);
    MQTTClient_disconnect(client, 10000);
    MQTTClient_destroy(&client);
    return rc;
}
```

How to connect using paho mqtt subscriber and also publish? Are there any other C language clients for this purpose? Or any other way in C language with code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a moment to read the doc on [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what to [avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Questions should have a single focused answerable question (e.g. how do I authenticate with PAHO-C) if you have other questions they should be asked seperately.

Comment: Also asking for examples is considered off topic on Stack Overflow. You need to show what you've tried, and explain how it doesn't work, then somebody will help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You set the `username` and `password` fields in the `MQTTClient_connectOptions` structure before you pass it to the `MQTTClient_connect()` function.

```
MQTTClient_create(&client, ADDRESS, CLIENTID,
    MQTTCLIENT_PERSISTENCE_NONE,NULL);
conn_opts.keepAliveInterval = 20;
conn_opts.cleansession = 1;
conn_opts.username = USERNAME
conn_opts.password = PASSWORD
```